# boundary value problem tolerance

Tags: differential-equations

I am trying to solve a system of coupled differential equations

```
xmax = 15;ϵ = 0.1;
s = NDSolve[{z''[x] == (1 - ϵ/2)*Sin[z[x]] - ϵ/2*Sin[y[x]], 
y''[x] == (1 - ϵ/2)*Sin[y[x]] - ϵ/2*Sin[z[x]], 
y[-xmax] == 0, y[xmax] == 2*π, z[-xmax] == 0,z[xmax] == 0}, {y, z}, {x, -xmax, xmax}, 
MaxSteps -> 10^8, AccuracyGoal -> Automatic, PrecisionGoal -> 50,
WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecision];
Plot[0.5*(y[x] + z[x]) /. s, {x, -xmax, xmax}, PlotRange -> All] //Print;
```

If I run this for small value of `xmax` like `xmax = 5`, it works just fine and gives the solution as expected. But for higher values of `xmax`, it runs into tolerance problems and doesn't give the solution as expected. What is the reason for this error?

I see now that for small $\epsilon$, I can uncouple the equation and solve the following equation but it still runs into the same tolerance problem:

```
 xmax = 5; ϵ = 0;
 s = NDSolve[{y''[x] == y[x] - 0.5*Sin[4*ArcTan[Exp[-x]]],y[-xmax] == 0, y[xmax] == 0}, y, 
{x, -xmax, xmax},MaxSteps -> 10^8, AccuracyGoal -> 8, PrecisionGoal -> 30, 
     WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecision];
 Plot[y[x] /. s, {x, -xmax, xmax}, PlotRange -> All] // Print;
```

How can I correct this?

Comment: Are you actually approximate $\infty$ with `xmax`?

Comment: @xzczd Yes, I am approaching infinity with $xmax$.

Answer (score 3):

**Comment**

The solution to the problem BVP system seems to be highly oscillatory. I tried to solve it with `Shooting` for different combination of `StartingInitialConditions`. The results are promising but not `100%` accurate.

```
Eq1 = z''[x] == (1 - ϵ/2)*Sin[z[x]] -ϵ/2*Sin[y[x]];
Eq2 = y''[x] == (1 - ϵ/2)*Sin[y[x]] -ϵ/2*Sin[z[x]];
bcs = {y[-xmax] == 0, y[xmax] == 2*\[Pi], z[-xmax] == 0,z[xmax] == 0};
sys = Join[{Eq1, Eq2}, bcs];
ϵ= 0.1;
```

`NDSolve` without any specified method,

```
s = NDSolve[sys, {y, z}, {x, -xmax, xmax}, MaxSteps -> 10^8,AccuracyGoal -> Automatic, 
PrecisionGoal -> 50,WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecision];
```

`NDSolve` with `Shooting` method for `StartingInitialConditions` on `-xmax`,

```
soln1 = NDSolve[sys, {y, z}, {x, -xmax, xmax}, 
   AccuracyGoal -> Automatic, WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecision, 
   Method -> {"Shooting", 
     "StartingInitialConditions" -> {y'[-xmax] == 0, 
       z'[-xmax] == 0}}];
```

`StartingInitialConditions` on `xmax`,

```
soln2 = NDSolve[sys, {y, z}, {x, -xmax, xmax}, 
   AccuracyGoal -> Automatic, WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecision, 
   Method -> {"Shooting", 
     "StartingInitialConditions" -> {y'[xmax] == 0, z'[xmax] == 0}}];
```

`StartingInitialConditions` on `0`,

```
soln3 = NDSolve[sys, {y, z}, {x, -xmax, xmax}, 
   AccuracyGoal -> Automatic, WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecision, 
   Method -> {"Shooting", 
     "StartingInitialConditions" -> {y[0] == 1.5, z[0] == 0}}];
```

Combining the results in one plot,

```
Plot[{0.5*(y[x] + z[x]) /. s, 0.5*(y[x] + z[x]) /. soln1, 
  0.5*(y[x] + z[x]) /. soln2, 0.5*(y[x] + z[x]) /. soln3}, {x, -xmax, 
  xmax}, PlotRange -> All,PlotLegends -> {"s", "soln1", "soln2", "soln3"}]
```

Now trying for different end points of the interval for `x`.

`xmax=5`

[image]

Checking whether the boundary conditions are satisfied or not?

[image]

```
xmax = 8;
```

[image]
[image]

```
xmax = 15;
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Somewhat surprisingly, I managed to find a solution with finite difference method (FDM). I've used [`pdetoae`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/127997/1871) for discretization:

```
xmax = 15; ϵ = 0.1;
set = {z''[x] == (1 - ϵ/2) Sin[z[x]] - 1/2 ϵ Sin[y[x]], 
       y''[x] == (1 - ϵ/2) Sin[y[x]] - 1/2 ϵ Sin[z[x]], 
       y[-xmax] == 0, y[xmax] == 2 π, z[-xmax] == 0, z[xmax] == 0};

points = 100;
difforder = 2;
grid = Array[# &, points, {-xmax, xmax}];
(* Definition of pdetoae isn't included in this post,
   please find it in the link above. *)
ptoa = pdetoae[{y, z}[x], grid, difforder];
var = # /@ grid & /@ {y, z} // Flatten;
ae = MapAt[#[[2 ;; -2]] &, ptoa@set, {{1}, {2}}];
sollst = FindRoot[ae, {#, 2 Pi} & /@ var, MaxIterations -> Infinity]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> **Remark**
>
> If you're confused about the usage of `#[[2 ;; -2]] &`, the following
>   is an alternative method for calculating `sollst`:
>
> ```
> fullae = Flatten@ptoa@set;
>
> lSSolve[obj_List, constr___, x_, opt : OptionsPattern[FindMinimum]] := 
>  FindMinimum[{1/2 obj^2 // Total, constr}, x, opt]
> lSSolve[obj_, rest__] := lSSolve[{obj}, rest]
>
> sollst = lSSolve[Subtract @@@ fullae, {#, 2 Pi} & /@ var, 
>      MaxIterations -> Infinity][[2]]; // AbsoluteTiming
> ```
>
> Notice this method is slower and less robust.

```
sol = Partition[sollst[[All, -1]], points];
ListLinePlot[sol, PlotRange -> All, DataRange -> {-xmax, xmax}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The initial guess `2 Pi` is important.

`FindRoot` still spits out `lstol` warning, but the solution meets the equation and boundary condition well:

```
{yfunc, zfunc} = ListInterpolation[#, grid] & /@ sol;
Subtract @@@ set /. {y -> yfunc, z -> zfunc};
%[[3 ;;]]
(* {0., 0., 0., 0.} *)
Plot[%%[[;; 2]] // Evaluate, {x, -xmax, xmax}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The error will be smaller if you enlarge `points`.

I'm not sure if this is the only solution of this boundary value problem (BVP).

I believe there're better approach(es) for attacking this BVP.

Comment: Thanks dear for a nice answer. I was thinking about FDM but wasn't able to do it.

Comment: @mmm This solution is a windfall, I should say. In my (limited) experience if `"Shooting"` fails to solve a BVP, FDM will probably fail, too.